# pdflatex crashes when inserting png

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex, miktex, png

I have a very simple problem. I have issues inserting `.png` in my LaTeX document. Here is an example:

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig.png}
   \end{document}
```

when I run `pdflatex` the document crashes (`pdflatex test.tex`). This has been bothering me for 3 months, with various documents and graphics. The solution so far has been to save the graphics as PDF and insert those in the source. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? This is how long `pdflatex` goes before crashing:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))) (test.aux)
(C:\Users\hhsie\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"))))
```

Many thanks in advance!

Update
Thank you for the quick responses. This is how it looks:
[image]

Here is a link to a  [zip of the folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7053611/test.zip)

This is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.12.18)  7 MAR 2017 11:31
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
(C:\Users\hhsie\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count88
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count89
\nofMParguments=\count90
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count91
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count92
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count93
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\
```

Comment: Doesn't it write anything else or is this just what your editor is showing? What is actually in the `.log` file?

Comment: Are you sure the file does really have the `.png` format?

Comment: 1.) don't use filenames that contain spaces or any sort of special character. they can cause a lot of problems for the LaTeX interpreter. 2.) even though it can stand alone, usually `\includegraphics{}` is embedded inside a floating environment, which means you should embed it inside `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I've updated the question with the output of the log file and a few details.

Comment: If otherwise your LaTeX works, meaning that something is wrong with your image. For example, the folowing MWE gives expewcted result `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig.png}
\end{document}` -- black box -- instead real image, which I haven't.

Comment: I should add:

The problem started when I got a new computer, so it may be related to the installation. I've tested it with many png's. In the example above I created my own png in paint. I don't think there is anything wrong with the file.

I should probably try to reinstall miktex.

Comment: I inspected the image (from the zip file) in a hex editor. Seems to be OK. Don't think the problem is with the image.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file and tested it in texlive (cygwin/windows8) it ran without error and included the png file in the pdf.

Comment: I've tested as well under TL 2016 and OpenSuSE Linux Leap -- all runs well...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a software update solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the quick responses. As you confirmed that the image was okay and the latex code was okay, I uninstalled Miktex 2.9 and installed TL 2016.

That solved the issue!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Updating miktex would probably have solved it too. (you had version 6100, I have 6210, and your image compiles fine).

Comment: Yes. You are probably right.